# How to avoid premature initialization if the variable is only used inside of a scope

Tags: java, pmd

It seems that avoiding premature initialization is a good programming practice.

I'm using PMD add-on for Eclipse, and I have had some "Found 'DD'-anomaly for variable 'var'". I know what this anomaly means. It means that a variable is prematurely initialized (the initialized value is never used).

However, I'm stuck with the following problem.

This is an general example of what I want to do.

```
String var = null;

if (someCondition()) {
    Object a;
    //some treatment on a
    var = "some value" + a.toString();
}
else {
    Object b;
    //some treatment on b
    var = "some other value" + b.toString();
}

return var;
```

And this would be the specific example of what I want to do :

```
String token = null;
String authorization = getAuthorization(token);

if (authorization != null) {
    String[] parts = authorization.split(" ");
    if (parts.length == 2 && "Bearer".equals(part[0])) {
        token = parts[1];
    }
}
return token;
```

.

The problem is that the variable is only used inside of a scope (in this case inside of the `if` block or the `else` block), but it is also the value to return. So if I declare it inside the `if` block or the `else` block to avoid premature initialization, then the variable won't exist outside of those blocks and I won't be able to return it.

I also want to avoid using multiple return statement, because that would cause another anomaly from PMD.

Is there a way to solve my problem while avoiding premature initialization?

Comment: Ah premature initialization... Those problems come out of nowhere....

Comment: Many struggle with premature initialization. Your code is perfectly fine, you can safely ignore this warning.

Comment: I don't know about PMD, but the `= null` is redundant and you can just remove it - would that keep PMD happy?

Comment: Kon : thank you for your response. As it is now, I think I'm going to do that (ignoring that warning).    CupawnTae : Unfortunately, doing so makes my compiler whine that the variable might have not been initialized.

Comment: @ProPhil then your example is not representative - in your example all code paths write a value to `var` before it's read, and in your real code something is reading it before it's written, so at the very least you'd need to provide an example where removing the initializer doesn't compile, but PMD still complains.

Comment: And you get the message about `String token`? Well, you _need_ to initialize that variable in order to use it here `getAuthorization(token)` and you might want to replace `token = parts[1];` with `return parts[1];`. No need to overwrite the variable `token`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a single LoC for this:

```
return someCondition() ? "some value" : "some other value";
```

---

The code in here:

```
String token;
String authorization = getAuthorization(token);

if (authorization != null) {
    String[] parts = authorization.split(" ");
    if (parts.length == 2 && "Bearer".equals(part[0])) {
        token = parts[1];
    }

return token;
```

In this case, you should initialize the variable with a default value, then initialize it wherever you need to:

```
String token = "";
String authorization = getAuthorization(token);
if (authorization != null) {
    String[] parts = authorization.split(" ");
    if (parts.length == 2 && "Bearer".equals(part[0])) {
        token = parts[1];
    }
} //I assume there's a missing closing bracket here...
return token;
```

Also, I would move `"Bearer"` into an `static final String` variable in order to avoid using literal strings directly in the code.

Comment: Thank you for your response. This would indeed work in the example I have given. However, I had in head that the if and else blocs had more LoCs, and the value of var would eventually depend of those LoCs. I should had specified.

Comment: @ProPhil provide **the relevant code to fix** and then I'll update the answer. Probably I can apply other refactor to that code.

Comment: I have re edited my original post as I forgot that token was initialized as null but I don't think that will change your response. You're right about Bearer, ill try to make a static final String with a significant name to avoid using a literal string. However, initializing token with the empty string "", isn't it pretty much the same as initializing token with null ? Regarding my problem with premature initialization, I mean.

Comment: @ProPhil it's not the same as the initial case because if you never initialize `token` **in this piece of code** then it cannot be initialized properly if both `if` conditions cannot be fulfilled, thus giving a compiler error. I guess there's more code to evaluate here that you're not showing (noticed because in your example you initialize the variable as a result of `if-else` evaluation when you here only use `if`) or the PMD warning is wrong and you should not worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply skip the initialization and leave the variable uninitialized. The JVM will initialize it implicitly with `null`. But this works only, if you can guarantee, that the variable will eventually be initialized in the following control flow. 
You may declare it `final`, indicating that it will only be assigned once. Positive side effect, the Eclipse compiler will indicate an error if one control flow exists, where variable is not assigned.

```
final String var;

if (someCondition()) {
   var = "some value";
}
else {
   var = "some other value";
}

return var;
```

Answer (score 0):

For the problem "Avoid using redundant field initializer for" the premature initialization on the field of a class, remove the initialization of fields.
String token = null;
String token; (quit initialization)